# Calculating point intersection from Azimuth and UTM coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, utm, azimuth

I have a control board point(CB) that I need to calculate the position of.
I took the azimuth and the elevation of that point relative of two other known points(of which are known Easting, Northing and Elevation in UTM coordinates). I thought of simplifying everything by projecting everything onto a horizontal plane and then get the intersection of two vectors given by the simple equation:

(y-y1)/(x-x1) = tan(90°-Azimuth1)

(y-y2)/(x-x2) = tan(90°-Azimuth2)

I made a change of variables for the azimuth, I hope it's correct. I attached a quick scheme of the process here below and a snippet of code that implements it.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

Az1 = np.radians(90-118.2711)
Az2 = np.radians(90-64.0205)

x_obh = 19354.8
x_p175 = 18774.533

y_obh = 49510.6
y_p175 = 48436.554

x = x_obh*np.tan(Az1)-x_p175*np.tan(Az2)-y_obh-y_p175
y = (x-x_obh)*np.tan(Az1)+y_obh
y2 = (x-x_p175)*np.tan(Az2)+y_p175

print(f'x: {x}')
print(f'y: {y}')
print(f'y2: {y2}')

x_array = np.array([x_obh,x_p175,x,x])
y_array = np.array([y_obh,y_p175,y,y2])
points_name = ['obh','p175','x1','x2']

plt.scatter(x_array,y_array,marker='x')
for i, txt in enumerate(points_name):
    plt.gca().annotate(txt, (x_array[i], y_array[i]))
plt.show()
```

The result was quite surprisingly different from what I expected. Do anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Is there something in the coordinate system that I am missing? Are my equations wrong?
Here below is a result of what I have got running the script. I was expecting y and y2 to be exactly in the same position, though.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for suggesting editing and commenting on my post. My apologies for not making things clear in the first place. You are correct, what I was trying to do is not what I got from my experiment. In fact, the result I got was completely different. My question is, in general, if not in specific, how can one work with UTM coordinates and azimuth together to find a point of intersection between two vectors?